# Python: how to count the fraction on 1 in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe `df` like the following:

```
df    
    ID    val
0   a      0
1   a      0
2   a      1
4   b      0
5   b      1
```

I would like to count the fraction of `1` for each ids in order to get something like

```
df1
    ID   val
0   a    0.33
1   b    0.5
```

Comment: Ok, please provide the code from your attempts. What went wrong, were there errors?

Answer (score 4):

An easy way is to group by `ID` and take the average of the `val` column:

```
print(df.groupby("ID").agg({"val": "mean"}).reset_index())
#  ID       val
#0  a  0.333333
#1  b  0.500000
```

Or more succinctly as pointed out by [@AlexRiley](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3923281/alex-riley):

```
df.groupby('ID', as_index=False).mean()
```

Comment: Or alternatively (to avoid `agg` and `reset_index()`) you could write `df.groupby('ID', as_index=False).mean()`

Answer (score -1):

Just groupby ID and sum and count them, then just divide each other, like this:

```
new_df = df.groupby("ID", as_index=False).agg({'val': ['sum', 'count']})
```

Then you only have to

```
new_df["val"] = new_df["sum"]/new_df["count"]
```